# What are the components of the domain and range for a stochastic process?

Tags: probability-theory, stochastic-processes

I am working through **Handbook of Heavy-Tailed Distributions in Asset Management and Risk Management** by Bianchi et al. At the very beginning of chapter three it dives into stochastic processes and definitions for them based on the pair $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ that brings a universe and a $\sigma$-algebra.  Where I am stuck is as follows:

A stochastic process is a collection of random variables $X = \{X_t\}_{t\geq 0}$ on $(\Omega, \mathcal{F})$ which can take values on $(E, \mathcal{E}$).  ***A process may be considered a mapping from $(\Omega \times \mathbb{R}_+, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}_+) \otimes \mathcal{F})$ into $(E, \mathcal{E})$ (usually $(\mathbb{R}, \mathcal{B}(\mathbb{R}))$), via $(\omega, t) \mapsto X(\omega, t) = X_t(\omega)$.***

(Emphasis mine.). I have gone through examples of filtrations, e.g. [this one](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2279205/example-of-filtration-in-probability-theory/2509598) with coin tosses.  I am seeking to fit the coin toss problem into the emphasized part of the definition given above.

In my thinking, $\Omega$ is the universe; $\mathbb{R}_+$ is, in the coin example, a subset of $\mathbb{N}$ for indexing; $\mathcal{F}$ is the filtration based on the history of coin flips (so $\mathcal{F} = (\mathcal{F_n})$); and the $\mathbb{R}$ in the image of the process is again $\mathbb{N}$ for indexing the coin toss sequence.  I am stuck, however, on 1) if this is correct, 2) what is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra in the second component of the domain of the coin tosses, and 3) what is the Borel $\sigma$-algebra over $\mathbb{R}$ in the range?  How would all of this fit into the coin toss example?

Thank you.